# Excel Add-In Form Sends Excel to Background When Form Closes

Tags: c#, forms, excel, popup

I have an Excel Add-In that pops up a form. If the user fills in some values and clicks the "Apply" button, the values are correctly sent to the underlying worksheet and the pop-up form closes. If, however, the user clicks on "Cancel," a Messagebox pops-up verifying that the user wants to cancel. Clicking "Yes" causes the pop-up form to close, but also sends Excel behind the previously active window -- very much like pressing Alt-Tab. This is not good!

Does anybody have any notions about how to keep Excel on top?

Thanks!

Randy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for all sorts of variations on ActiveWindow/ActiveView but couldn't find anything applicable. Finally I went around the Mulberry bush to come up with this:

```
        IntPtr excelWindow = excelWindow = SpreadsheetApplicationFactoryBase.TheExcelApp.ExcelWin32Window.Handle;
        Win32.SetActiveWindow(excelWindow);
```

Ugly, but it works. The factory is a small class that creates/returns the Excel instance.

I very much appreciate the input.

Randy

Comment: I'd still like to know why the Yes/No confirmation box sends the whole application to the background. That just doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could put this in right after the message box `ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious`
 And test with

```
Debug.Print ActiveWindow.Caption
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Debug.Print ActiveWindow.Caption
```

Comment: Am I really stupid? I don't have ActiveWindow, or at least, IntelliSense isn't recognizing one. Or, is this just your shorthand for something instantiated?

Comment: Intellisense had it pop up for me... Maybe you could try `Application.ActiveWindow`. That's weird though. If I get back on a Windows machine again I'll try again.

Comment: Yeah, just confirmed. If I start typing "activew" then ctrl+space completes it. Not attached to an object explicitly.